# What looks like a table within postgresql table partition? How do I investigate?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I'm trying to investigate a database bloat issue and I've found something within a table partiion that I don't understand and can't find a way to investigate. I apologize if I'm missing the obvious, my knowladge and experience with databases is sparse.

Postgresql 9.0

I have a database that tracks historical information about DHCP assignments, it has four tables: log, leases, pools, messages.

Each table is broken into partitions by day so we can drop the partitions after 30 days. Some of these partitions have >4M rows added a day.

Looking at most of the partitions gives me what I would expect:

```
dhcplog=> \d+ leases
                                                Table "public.leases"
   Column   |           Type           |                      Modifiers                      | Storage | Description 
------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------
 id         | bigint                   | not null default nextval('leases_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   | 
 ip         | inet                     |                                                     | main    | 
 mac        | macaddr                  |                                                     | plain   | 
 start      | timestamp with time zone |                                                     | plain   | 
 stop       | timestamp with time zone |                                                     | plain   | 
 switchport | integer                  |                                                     | plain   | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "leases_switchport_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (switchport) REFERENCES switchports(id)
Child tables: partitions.leases_2014_08_02,
              partitions.leases_2014_08_03,
              partitions.leases_2014_08_04,
              partitions.leases_2014_08_05,
              partitions.leases_2014_08_06, ...
```

But in one of the tables I have what looks like references to two other tables as part of the list of partitions (messages and logs):

```
dhcplog=> \d+ log
                                               Table "public.log"
 Column  |           Type           |                    Modifiers                     | Storage  | Description 
---------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id      | bigint                   | not null default nextval('log_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 date    | timestamp with time zone |                                                  | plain    | 
 host    | character varying(30)    |                                                  | extended | 
 message | character varying(255)   |                                                  | extended | 
Child tables: messages,
              partitions.log_2014_10_01,
              partitions.log_2014_10_02, ...
              partitions.log_2014_11_07,
              pools
```

I'm not able to get a row count or any information from those partitions though:

```
dhcplog=> SELECT count(*) FROM partitions.messages;
ERROR:  relation "partitions.messages" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT count(*) FROM partitions.messages;
                             ^
```

But the count works on all of the others.

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Thanks. -sjs

Comment: The table name is `public.messages`. Just use `select count(*) from public.messages;` The other tables (`log_xxx`) are located in the schema `partitions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the output of \d+ log you should notice that the child table messages is listed as messages not as partitions.messages. So querying a table partitions.messages is not going to work.

The following should work:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM messages;
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. Why would it show up in the listing for the table log? It is its own table with partitions. I would hesitate to count the entire table as a single day has 8.3M records.

Comment: @SeanSchluntz: "*Why would it show up in the listing for the table log*" - because someone created it like that: `create table messages ( ..) inherits (log);`